# Консоль для питон бота

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю бота в **discord**, через которого я смогу управлять компъютером через телефон,и **хочу сделать консоль в которой будет выводитса действие которое было сделано на пк**(по типу: на вашем пк была открыта **Opera** и тд), и писалось в определёный текстовый канал **(что-то похожее на канал аудита, только про действие сделаные на пк, а не в дискорде)**, но не знаю как это сделать, точнее не знаю библиотеку которая могла б такое сделать, если есть такая библиотека напишите пожалуйста, **буду очень благодарен**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько вам подойдет моя идея, но из самого простого, можно отслеживать активные процессы и окна на которых сейчас фокус.

```
import time
import os
import psutil
import pygetwindow as gw # pip install pygetwindow psutil

while True:
    active_window = gw.getActiveWindow()
    processes = []
    for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        processes.append((process.info['pid'], process.info['name']))

    print(f'Активное окно: {active_window}')
    print('Активные процессы:')
    for pid, name in processes:
        print(f'PID: {pid}, Название: {name}')

    time.sleep(5)  # Пауза между обновлениями
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # Очистка консоли
```

Алгоритм вижу примерно такой:

Записываем список активных процессов, при появлении в списке нового процесса сигнализируем о том, что запустилась новая программа и т.д.

Так же можно попытается обыграть всё и через активное окно в фокусе. Сменился фокус - сигнализируем.

[**Функции для работы c PID модуля psutil в Python**](https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-psutil-python/spisok-zapushchennykh-protsessov/)

[**PyGetWindow**](https://pygetwindow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: а можно сделать так что бы оно не писало каждые 5 секунд, а например когда програма запустилась?
Типа: Я запустил програму и оно сразу написало что открылась програма в консоль, если нельзя то спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: @Apelcin Конечно можно. Я вам просто показал какие данные можно получить. А дальше если направление мысли вам нравится, обдумайте алгоритм что б реализовать вашу задумку.

Comment: Окей, спасибо вам, хорошего дня.